# "Cows and Bulls" game

Tags: javascript, beginner

We are working on an assignment where we have to generate code that will play player one in the game Cows and Bulls. I am working on a function that generates the code based on the values for `codeSize` and `codeChars`. `CodeSize` being the size of the code, `CodeChars` being alpha or numeric, depending on what is selected by the user. However, I cannot seem to get ride of the duplicates.

```
// Check if we are not allowed to include duplicate characters:
             if (nodupes === true) {
                 // True if character already used:
                 var added = (used.indexOf(chr) !== -1);
                 // Skip the Character if already used:
                 if (added === true) {
                     continue;
                    }
                 // Add Character to the list of used ones:
                 used += chr;
//                   alert(used);
                }
             // Add Character to the output string:
             output += chr;
            //    alert(output);
            } 
 while (output.length < codeSize);
      //   alert(typeof(output));
        //     alert(output);
             return output;  // Not working Correctly string still has duplicate characters.
         if (output.length == codeSize) {
             result = output;
         alert(result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please look at this [guide for posting a good question.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562). I have absolutely no idea about what the "Cows and Bulls" game is, could you add some more pure English description about what that is? And what your code is doing?

Answer (score 3):

First thing, let's clean the comments and indentation, because what you have right there is just unreadable.

First, fix indentation...

```
        // Check if we are not allowed to include duplicate characters:
        if (nodupes === true) {
            // True if character already used:
            var added = (used.indexOf(chr) !== -1);
            // Skip the Character if already used:
            if (added === true) {
                continue;
            }
            // Add Character to the list of used ones:
            used += chr;
            //                   alert(used);
        }
        // Add Character to the output string:
        output += chr;
        //    alert(output);
    } 
    while (output.length < codeSize);
    //   alert(typeof(output));
    //     alert(output);
    return output;  // Not working Correctly string still has duplicate characters.
    if (output.length == codeSize) {
        result = output;
        alert(result);
    }
}
```

And it makes absolutely no sense.

It didn't before, but now we can at least see what's wrong with it:

1. Your code starts halfway. Presumably inside a do-while loop.
2. You return output, then the function continues with more code.

Those are the main problems.

The second one is fatal, however; this is broken code. Especially with the comment "// Not working Correctly string still has duplicate characters."